# I can't update Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, package-management, upgrade, dependencies, error-handling

I can't update, install or even remove program without getting this error message:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpython3.7-stdlib : Depends: 
libpython3.7-minimal (= 3.7.0- 
1+xenial2) but 3.7.1-1~18.04 is installed
 python3.7 : Depends: 
 libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.1-1~18.04) but 3.7.0-1+xenial2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have a version conflict caused by an incompatible non-Ubuntu package from some PPA or other non-Ubuntu source. The usual answer is to uninstall all packages from that unwisely-added source, then delete the source. Please edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: if you have text, please add it to your question (and not pictures of text).  Pictures are much harder to read & we cannot copy/paste information from them easily.   User535733 is spot on (as always) - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libpython3.7-minimal shows your sources are not official (added PPAs or sources) that are creating conflicts.  You could `apt-cache policy  <package>` to show the conflicting source, but we don't know the <package> name due partial paste (*it's higher up in the listing you pasted from*)